# PHP array_slice or equivalent on array of arrays that are keyed by ID

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, php-7, php-7.1

I have a multi-dimensional array that is keyed by `uuid's` and need to slice/pop/unset an element by uuid (i.e., if I had `a410463e-7fe2-4fba-8733-a812c0ee8c54` and wanted to remove that item by that uuid) so that the result is essentially the same minus the one item that was removed:

```
array:5 [
  "5fc29794-9e08-4944-ba6d-4a5fcde5c88b" => array:3 [
    "id" => "5fc29794-9e08-4944-ba6d-4a5fcde5c88b"
    "name" => "fuga"
    "value" => 0
  ]
  "a410463e-7fe2-4fba-8733-a812c0ee8c54" => array:3 [
    "id" => "a410463e-7fe2-4fba-8733-a812c0ee8c54"
    "name" => "nihil"
    "value" => 0
  ]
  "c141d973-91fe-4227-8985-04bd0665f4a8" => array:3 [
    "id" => "c141d973-91fe-4227-8985-04bd0665f4a8"
    "name" => "eaque"
    "value" => 0
  ]
  "17030897-1aa9-487d-a4be-d574dd0c9d9b" => array:3 [
    "id" => "17030897-1aa9-487d-a4be-d574dd0c9d9b"
    "name" => "eveniet"
    "value" => 3
  ]
  "901d9f8f-573f-444f-8562-0cdf5888ba6e" => array:3 [
    "id" => "901d9f8f-573f-444f-8562-0cdf5888ba6e"
    "name" => "in"
    "value" => 6
  ]
]
```

I know how to slice by index, but am having trouble finding resources on how this might be achieved. This is for a `phpunit` test. I've tried `unset`, but can't seem to store that in a variable or just call it in an assertion:

```
unset($array1[$id]);
unset($array2[$id]);
```

Does not persist the change.

```
$newUnchanged = unset($array1[$id]);
$oldUnchanged = unset($array2[$id]);
```

Throws `syntax error, unexpected 'unset'` error. Ultimately I want to assert that all of the unchanged items remained the same as prior to a single item being updated. I've also tried this ugly business which is removing a single item, but not the correct one:

```
$keyOne = array_search($id, array_keys($array1), true);
$oldUnchanged = array_slice($array1, $keyOne, null, true);

$keyTwo = array_search($id, array_keys($array2), true);
$newUnchanged = array_slice($array2, $keyTwo, null, true);

// Shows that the item that I wanted to slice still exists in both arrays
dd($id, $oldUnchanged, $newUnchanged);

// ^ Causes this test to fail
$this->assertEquals($oldUnchanged, $newUnchaged);
```

Comment: So you're just wanting to remove an item based on it's key?

Comment: Yes. But the key is an id and not an index.

Comment: Ok. I'm a little confused at the minute since the keys in your example are the same as the ids. Can you explain why something like `unset()` wouldn't work? Also, are you able to provide the code you have so far?

Comment: What item(s) do you want to remove? Can you include the array as an var_export instead?

Comment: I started with unset, but I'm getting a `syntax error, unexpected 'unset'`. I'm trying to remove any item I have the id for. The use case is that I am updating just one of the items and then attempting to test that all of the others were unchanged. The above array was cast from a jsonb postgres column.

Comment: I'm assuming that `$service` is a model and  `all_service_data` is a collection?

Comment: $service is an Eloquent model and all_service_data is an array cast from a jsonb column.

Comment: I updated the above code to attempt to be even more clear. Forget the origin of the arrays. They are in the above format, keyed by a uuid, and I have a single uuid and need to remove the element that is keyed by that uuid from both arrays to compare the two arrays, minus the one element that I updated and then removed from them to ensure that the items I did not want to update did not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I have to clone the arrays before I can unset them

```
$oldUnchanged = $array1;
unset($oldUnchanged[$id]);

$newUnchanged = $array2;
unset($newUnchanged[$id]);
```